# Azure SQL - Take Backup of sepcific tables to another Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-backups

I was trying to take specfic tables data in an Azure SQL DB and then dump this data in to a new table of same structure inside another existing SQL database. I don't want full back-up and both Azure SQL Databases are inside the same Azure SQL Server. It shows some security errors and so I thought I might be doing something wrong. Any tools/automated way to achieve this in Azure?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use SQL Server Management Studio to generate a script of the data to copy from table A on Database A to table A on Database B as explained [here](https://blog.atwork.at/post/How-to-copy-table-data-between-Azure-SQL-Databases#:%7E:text=Here%C2%B4s%20the%20quick%20How%20to%20copy%20data%20from,and%20select%20the%20desired%20table%20%22Newsletters%22%20and%20%22Next%22.).

1. Right click the source database and select "Generate Scripts..."

[image]

2. Click "Next" and skip the introduction. Click "Select specific database objects" and select the desired table "Newsletters" and "Next".

[image]

3. Now comes the important, "Advanced" part: Generate a script by selecting the output to a file, to the clipboard or to a new query window. Click on "Advanced" and in the option "Types of data to script", select "Data only" as shown here. Click "OK".

[image]

4. Select the "Types of data to script" as needed...
   Now confirm the script generation with "Next".
5. The script has been generated. Click "Finish" to close the wizard. You will get the generated script in a new query window in the background.
6. Open a new query window in the destination database.
7. Then, copy the generated script into the destination query windows connected to the destination database and execute it (F5).

Check the result. All data should be available in the destination database in the table.